# Python cgi script not opening a html file in local directory

Tags: python, html, redirect, cgi-bin

I have a simple python module that generates a web page containing a list of links. This page is automatically opened in a browser through `webbrowser.open('file://' + file.name)`: no problems here.
From this web page, when clicking on on a link (which has a href like `http://localhost/cgi-bin/script.py?param1=Something`) it lunches a cgi script that performs some operations with the passed value and at the end generates a new web page, stored locally in my machine (e.g. in a path like `/home/user/web/out/`) in a folder where I correctly set all rwx permissions.
Well, I've been trying to automatically open this new page in the browser for two days now, attempting with all the solutions I found searching through documentations and forums. I tried with `webbrowser.open()` again, but then I realized that I can't use it because from the web server  I can't open a new browser window itself. Then I tried with redirection, printing first a header (`print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"`) and then

```
print "Status: 302 Moved"
print "Location: file:///home/user/web/out/abc.html\n\n"`
```

but this just shows a plain blank page. I gave a try to other redirecting solutions, like

```
print "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0' url='file:///home/user/web/out/abc.html'>"
print "<script type="text/javascript">location.href='file:///home/user/web/out/abc.html';</script>"
print "<script type="text/javascript">windows.open('file:///home/user/web/out/abc.html');</script>"
```

I even tried inserting a Button with a `POST` method that triggers the opening of the new page, without success: I keep getting a plain blank page.
It is worth to say that, if I manually open this `abc.html` page in the browser, it is properly shown.

I think this has to do with the fact that the html page I'm opening from the web server is in locally stored, but I don't know how to solve this. Can somebody point me to the right direction?

Comment: I am just guessing but: if you could redirect to local files then everybody hosting a website would be able to read all content from you computer. So maybe you can not redirect to local files from a website. But you can open the local files with your server and serve the content.

Comment: @User Uhm... what do you mean by 'serve the content'? I actually managed to write the new web page to be opened in `cgi-bin/out/abc.html`, but still I don't get the script to open it or even redirect to it

Comment: A CGI-Script can not redirect I remember. `self.send_response(200, "Script output follows")` in `http.server`.

Answer (score 0):

A CGI-Script can not redirect I remember.

```
Note that status code 200 is sent prior to execution of a CGI script, so
scripts cannot send other status codes such as 302 (redirect).
```

This is some code:

```
self.send_response(200, "Script output follows")
```

module: http.server (Python 3)

But you can just open the file and use `sys.stdout.write` or `shutil` to copy its content to stdout.

Comment: copy the content of the html file to `stdout` didn't do the job. I want to try creating a web server and separate the two things, but I hoped it could be faster and easier

Comment: You can still modify the http server.